# What tools I need to find intersection of terms vs text

Tags: java, scala, full-text-search

Having some text source, say Wikipedia article I want to find all the substrings from some specific set. For example input:

- Text: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Group_of_Funds
- Terms: "hedge funds", "fund", "british currency would drop", "missing"

... I want to get: "hedge funds", "fund", "british currency would drop" as a result, or "Yes"
, "Yes", "Yes", "No".

I can obviously write some more-less smart algorithm to achieve this, but I'd rather had some already implemented library to get what I want (preferably in Java/Scala environment). Is there anything I can use?

Comment: Is retrieving the text part of the question? Do you only want exact matching? What are your performance requirements (e.g. do you need realtime, millions of queries per document, etc.)?

Comment: Are simple regexes http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex sufficient

Answer (score -1):

Using only Java libraries, you can do something like this:

```
  List<String> listOfWords = Arrays.asList("hedge funds", "fund", "british currency would drop");

  for (String searchWrd : listOfWords) {
      URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Group_of_Funds");
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());
      scan.useDelimiter("\\s+");
      while(scan.hasNext())
          if(searchWrd.equals(scan.next())) {
              containsString=true;
              break;
          }
      if(containsString)
          System.out.println("Contains: " + searchWrd);
      else 
          System.out.println("Does't contain: " + searchWrd);
  }
```

Comment: In fact it's a core java (not third party library), so I would not call it *Java libraries*. Having said this, I don't know who might want to downvote you -- perfectly fine answer to the question.